# Oracle SQL CASE statement pseudo column

Tags: sql, oracle, case

There are 2 tables - orders & config_check.

```
create table orders (order_created date,
                     cus_no varchar2(20),
                     order_num number,
                     pay_type varchar2(30),
                     MFC date,
                     prod_no varchar2(15) );
                     
create table config_check (check_type varchar2(100),
                     field_name varchar2(10),
                     field_value varchar2(15),
                     start_date date,
                     end_date date
                    );
                    
insert into orders values ('20-NOV-21', 'GT-19Y67', 489, 'Credit Card', NULL, '1000');
insert into orders values ('07-OCT-21', 'NU-20D73', 567, 'Cash on Delivery', '14-OCT-21', '1001');
insert into orders values ('17-NOV-21', 'JP-16V81', 789, 'Cash on Delivery', NULL, '1101');
insert into orders values ('20-NOV-21', 'DZ-17T92', 837, 'Net Banking', '23-NOV-21', '1002');
insert into orders values ('16-SEP-21', 'RJ-18W107', 124, 'Cash on Delivery', NULL, '1002');
insert into orders values ('18-NOV-21', 'KI-19A39', 638, 'Cash on Delivery', NULL, '1000');
insert into orders values ('19-NOV-21', 'FT-20U86', 347, 'Net Banking', NULL, '1002');
insert into orders values ('19-NOV-21', 'FT-20U86', 347, 'Net Banking', NULL, '1110');



insert into config_check VALUES ('Invalid Orders Check', 'PROD_NO', '1000', '16-NOV-21', '30-NOV-21' );
insert into config_check VALUES ('Invalid Orders Check', 'PROD_NO', '1101', '08-SEP-21', '21-SEP-21' );
insert into config_check VALUES ('Invalid Orders Check', 'PROD_NO', '1002', '16-NOV-21', '30-NOV-21' );
insert into config_check VALUES ('Cust Bday Offer', 'CUST_NO', '845796', '13-AUG-21', '23-AUG-21' );

commit;
```

Task is to find cus_no, order_num where the order is invalid in one of the 3 conditions :

1. pay_type is 'Cash on Delivery' - when this happens then a pseudo column named comments should have the message 'This order does not qualify for CoD'
2. column MFC is not null - when this happens then a pseudo column named comments should have the message 'This order can not be an MFC'
3. when an additional product is added which is not listed in config_check table. This one needs some explanation. So I will try my best with the above table examples to explain in detail. In config_check table there are 2 PROD_NOs (1000 and 1002) for CHECK_TYPE 'Invalid Orders Check' which started on 16-Nov-21. Today's date is 21-NOV-2021. So only those 2 rows can be considered where today's date lies between start and end date. Now order number 347 has a product number 1110 which is not in config_check table. In such a case the pseudo column named comments should have the message 'Non listed items can not be ordered'.

I have got the 1st 2 conditions but have not been able to get the 3rd one. Here is my attempt at the query :

```
select o.CUS_NO, o.ORDER_NUM,
       CASE 
            WHEN o.pay_type = 'Cash on Delivery' THEN 'This order does not qualify for Cod'
            WHEN o.MFC IS NOT NULL THEN 'This order can not be an MFC'
       END comments
       from orders o INNER JOIN 
( select * from config_check where check_type = 'Invalid Orders Check' and sysdate between start_date and end_date) c
ON (o.prod_no = c.field_value)
where o.ORDER_CREATED > c.start_date
  AND (o.pay_type = 'Cash on Delivery' OR o.MFC IS NOT NULL);
```

The above query gives the result as :

1. DZ-17T92    837 This order can not be an MFC
2. KI-19A39    638 This order does not qualify for Cod

[image]

The Case should have another WHEN clause for the 3rd condition and the same should be in the bracketed AND clause at the last. I cannot get the 3rd condition in the CASE block. Can someone please help me get the desired result? The desired output should be

1. DZ-17T92    837 This order can not be an MFC
2. KI-19A39    638 This order does not qualify for Cod
3. FT-20U86    347 Non listed items can not be ordered

[image]

Looking for help or even pointers will be great. Thank You for reading such a long post.

Edit : I am having trouble pasting the query output in table format. I will share the output in jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

You use else condition in **CASE** statement.

```
select o.CUS_NO, o.ORDER_NUM,
       CASE 
            WHEN o.pay_type = 'Cash on Delivery' THEN 'This order does not qualify for Cod'
            WHEN o.MFC IS NOT NULL THEN 'This order can not be an MFC'
        enter code here    **ELSE 'Non listed item can not be ordered'**                
       END as  comments
       from orders o INNER JOIN 
( select * from config_check where check_type = 'Invalid Orders Check' and sysdate between start_date and end_date) c
ON (o.prod_no = c.field_value)
where o.ORDER_CREATED > c.start_date
  AND (o.pay_type = 'Cash on Delivery' OR o.MFC IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: I was not able to get that <enter code her> part.

Comment: I have got query:
select o1.cus_no, o1.order_num, 'Non listed items can not be ordered' com from orders o1 where exists ( select 1 from
(select o.* from orders o INNER JOIN ( select * from config_check where check_type = 'Invalid Orders Check' and sysdate between start_date and end_date) c
ON (o.prod_no = c.field_value) where o.ORDER_CREATED > c.start_date) i where i.ORDER_NUM = o1.ORDER_NUM
AND o1.prod_no NOT IN (select FIELD_VALUE from config_check where check_type = 'Invalid Orders Check' and sysdate between start_date and end_date)
) ;
which gets me the order num 347